# Lattice packing

Tags: nt.number-theory, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, lattices, geometry-of-numbers

Let $\Lambda$ be a lattice in $R^n$ and $R>0$ a real number.
Consider the number $N$ of points in $\Lambda$ of norm less than $R$.  Let $R$ goes to infinity. What can be said about the asymptotic behaviour of $N$?

Comment: It behaves as $(1+o(1))\times$volume(of the ball of radius $R)/$volume(of the fundamental domain of $\Lambda$). Is this enough for you?

Comment: Thank's. It is enough for my purpose.

Comment: See Lemma 19.5 in https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.785/2017fa/LectureNotes19.pdf